# How to add items from a list of dictionarys to another list using IF conditions

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement

I want to build my own list of dictionaries by getting certain keys and values from another list of dictionaries. I also need to check if some keys exists or not to filter them and if some of them exists, extract only some parts.

Here you are the original list of dictionaries:

```
messages_raw_json = [
        #item_dict_1
        {
            "_id": "1",
            "msg": "Hi friends",
            "ts": "2021-11-20T06:14:42.374Z",
            "u": {
                "_id": "user1",
                "username": "verz",
                "name": "vrodriguez"
            },
            "_updatedAt": "2021-11-20T06:14:42.586Z",
            "urls": []
        },

         #item_dict_2
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "ts": "2021-11-18T16:52:37.620Z",
            "msg": "",
            "u": {
                "_id": "user2",
                "username": "2cats",
                "name": "Two Cats"
            },
            "_updatedAt": "2021-11-18T16:54:34.285Z",
            "urls": [],
            "t": "msg_removed"
        },

         #item_dict_3
        {
            "_id": "3",
            "ts": "2021-11-18T16:52:37.620Z",
            "msg": "",
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "ts": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "title": "image.png",
                    "image_url": "/file-upload/SpacZwkFjWRzdW8eh/image.png",
                    "description": "testing uploading image",
                }
            ],
            "u": {
                "_id": "user3",
                "username": "blas3",
                "name": "blasito"
            },
            "_updatedAt": "2021-11-18T16:54:34.267Z",
            "urls": []
        },

         #item_dict_4
        {
            "_id": "4",
            "t": "user_join",
            "ts": "2021-11-17T20:05:48.043Z",
            "msg": "testing",
            "u": {
                "_id": "user4",
                "username": "micheal11",
                "name": "george"
            },
            "_updatedAt": "2021-11-17T20:05:48.065Z"
        },

         #item_dict_5
        {
            "_id": "5",

            "msg": "Another message here",
            "ts": "2021-11-14T19:59:11.428Z",
            "u": {
                "_id": "user5",
                "username": "Mason78",
                "name": "stuart"
            },
            "_updatedAt": "2021-11-14T19:59:11.770Z",
            "urls": [
                {
                    "url": "https://wa.me/c/12345",
                    "headers": {
                        "contentType": "text/html; charset=\"utf-8\""
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

My first condition is to check if the item dict includes a key named 't', in that case, I want to skip it. This IF statement handles correctly the situation:

```
if 't' in message.keys():
   continue
```

Then I want to get the url from the key 'urls', if this is not empty.
And same for 'attachments', I'd like to get only the values from 'title', 'image_url' and 'description' but here is where I'm struggling.

This is the code I wrote which is not working. I understand why (not all the items have the keys I'm trying to retrieve) but honestly, as I'm a beginner in Python, I don't know how to write the other conditions to make it work. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
messages = []
for message in messages_raw_json:
    if 't' in message.keys():
        continue
    data = {
        'time': message['ts'],
        'name': message['u']['name'],
        'username': message['u']['username'],
        'msg': message['msg'],
        'url': message['urls'][0]['url'],
        'attach_file': message['attachments']['title'],
        'attach_file': message['attachments']['image_url'],
        'attach_file': message['attachments']['description']
        }
    messages.append(data)

print(messages)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I am hearing, you are trying to get all the data but ones with the key "t".

To get a piece of data that you are *not sure exists*, just use:

```
message.get(key, exceptionvalue)
# Where 'exception value' is simply what it returns if the key does not exist
```

For example:

```
data  = {
        "url" : message.get("url", None)
        }
```

Note that trying to get each and every value is not efficient. If it was a 1d dictionary, you could create a list of keys (and exception values) and just iterate through, but that is not really plausible in this case.

Comment: Thank you Larry for the tip, indeed, like that it checks and add the value of the key if exists and if not, just add the key and the value None. 

There is something a bit trickier in my example, because I don't want to capture the entire value from 'attachments' or 'urls', just some, like 'title' or 'description' from attachments or 'url' from 'urls'

Comment: ... in which you can probably use `.get("attachments",{}).get("title",None)` or something to that effect

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this issue. Sadly, it doesn't work as you propose :/ I tried some variations without luck.

Comment: No problem - hopefully it helped with getting your program onto the write track, though.